# Structs depending on JSON data

Tags: ios, json, swift, struct

I am currently working with a financial market API where I can get JSON data as a single stock ticker/quote or in a batch.

I am able to decode the JSON data if I know what stock ticker I am trying to request from the API ahead of time.

What I am struggling with is how to write my `structs` so that I can decode any stock ticker the user selects.

For example, in development I know I will want to request stock data on AAPL, so I'll write the appropriate `struct` (below), but lets say, on actual deployment, I'll want to take a look at TSLA stock data, in such a case, I wouldn't have the appropriate TSLA `struct` written, because I only have a `struct` written for AAPL, thus receiving an error.

Is there any way to write some sort of dynamic `struct` or use a Swift library that can help solve this problem?

I will post a snippet of the JSON data and my `struct` below.

```
{"AAPL":
    {"quote":
        {"symbol":"AAPL",
            "companyName":"Apple, Inc.",
            "primaryExchange":"NASDAQ",
            "calculationPrice":"close",
            "open":112.67,
            "openTime":1600781401038,
            "openSource":"official",
            "close":111.81,
            "closeTime":1600804800589,
            "closeSource":"official",
            "high":112.86,
            "highTime":1600819199980,
            "highSource":"15 minute delayed price",
            "low":109.16,
            "lowTime":1600786957213,
            "lowSource":"15 minute delayed price",
            "latestPrice":111.81,
            "latestSource":"Close",
            "latestTime":"September 22, 2020",
            "latestUpdate":1600804800589,
            "latestVolume":183055373,
            "iexRealtimePrice":111.545,
            "iexRealtimeSize":56,
            "iexLastUpdated":1600806216383,
            "delayedPrice":110.6,
            "delayedPriceTime":1600819199980,
            "oddLotDelayedPrice":127.67,
            "oddLotDelayedPriceTime":1600807552123,
            "extendedPrice":110.6,
            "extendedChange":-1.21,
            "extendedChangePercent":-0.01082,
            "extendedPriceTime":1600819199980,
            "previousClose":110.08,
            "previousVolume":195713815,
            "change":1.73,
            "changePercent":0.01572,
            "volume":183055373,
            "iexMarketPercent":0.007153872636301017,
            "iexVolume":1303096,
            "avgTotalVolume":196415720,
            "iexBidPrice":0,
            "iexBidSize":0,
            "iexAskPrice":0,
            "iexAskSize":0,
            "iexOpen":null,
            "iexOpenTime":null,
            "iexClose":111.8,
            "iexCloseTime":1600804792007,
            "marketCap":1938483513000,
            "peRatio":33.69,
            "week52High":137.98,
            "week52Low":53.15,
            "ytdChange":0.50212,
            "lastTradeTime":1600804799962,
            "isUSMarketOpen":false
        }
    },
    "FB":
    {"quote":
        {"symbol":"FB",
            "companyName":"Facebook, Inc.",
            "primaryExchange":"NASDAQ",
            "calculationPrice":"close",
            "open":253.31,
            "openTime":1600781400128,
            "openSource":"official",
            "close":254.75,
            "closeTime":1600804800789,
            "closeSource":"official",
            "high":255.32,
            "highTime":1600819191691,
            "highSource":"15 minute delayed price",
            "low":248.22,
            "lowTime":1600787261157,
            "lowSource":"15 minute delayed price",
            "latestPrice":254.75,
            "latestSource":"Close",
            "latestTime":"September 22, 2020",
            "latestUpdate":1600804800789,
            "latestVolume":30401995,
            "iexRealtimePrice":254.695,
            "iexRealtimeSize":100,
            "iexLastUpdated":1600804797803,
            "delayedPrice":253.8,
            "delayedPriceTime":1600819191691,
            "oddLotDelayedPrice":254.74,
            "oddLotDelayedPriceTime":1600804799413,
            "extendedPrice":253.8,
            "extendedChange":-0.95,
            "extendedChangePercent":-0.00373,
            "extendedPriceTime":1600819191691,
            "previousClose":248.15,
            "previousVolume":24709378,
            "change":6.6,
            "changePercent":0.0266,
            "volume":30401995,
            "iexMarketPercent":0.025296103101128724,
            "iexVolume":769052,
            "avgTotalVolume":25154911,
            "iexBidPrice":0,
            "iexBidSize":0,
            "iexAskPrice":0,
            "iexAskSize":0,
            "iexOpen":null,
            "iexOpenTime":null,
            "iexClose":254.695,
            "iexCloseTime":1600804797803,
            "marketCap":725735292113,
            "peRatio":30.89,
            "week52High":304.67,
            "week52Low":137.1,
            "ytdChange":0.241301,
            "lastTradeTime":1600804800789,
            "isUSMarketOpen":false}
    }
}

----

struct iexTicker: Decodable {
    let AAPL: iexQuote
    let FB: iexQuote
}

struct iexQuote: Decodable {
    let quote: iexData
}
   
struct iexData: Decodable {
    let symbol: String?
    let companyName: String?
    let primaryExchange: String?
    let calculationPrice: String?
    let open: Double?
    let openTime: Double?
    let openSource: String?
    let close: Double?
    let closeTime: Double?
    let closeSource: String?
    let high: Double?
    let highTime: Double?
    let low: Double?
    let lowTime: Double?
    let lowSource: String?
    let latestPrice: Double?
    let latestSource: String?
    let latestTime: String?
    let latestUpdate: Double?
    let latestVolume: Double?
    let iexRealtimePrice: Double?
    let iexRealtimeSize: Double?
    let iexLastUpdated: Double?
    let delayedPrice: Double?
    let delayedPriceTime: Double?
    let oddLotDelayedPrice: Double?
    let oddLotDelayedPriceTime: Double?
    let extendedPrice: Double?
    let extendedChange: Double?
    let extendedChangePercent: Double?
    let extendedPriceTime: Double?
    let previousClose: Double?
    let previousVolume: Double?
    let change: Double?
    let changePercent: Double?
    let volume: Double?
    let iexMarketPercent: Double?
    let iexVolume: Double?
    let avgTotalVolume: Double?
    let iexBidPrice: Double?
    let iexBidSize: Double?
    let iexAskPrice: Double?
    let iexAskSize: Double?
    let iexOpen: Double?
    let iexOpenTime: Double?
    let iexClose: Double?
    let iexCloseTime: Double?
    let marketCap: Double?
    let peRatio: Double?
    let week52High: Double?
    let week52Low: Double?
    let ytdChange: Double?
    let lastTradeTime: Double?
    let isUSMarketOpen: Bool?
}
```

Comment: Aren't the structs for AAPL and TSLA the same? It looks like you just need to decode a dictionary of type `[TickerName: IEXQuote]` (where `TickerName` is just an alias for `String`)

Comment: I think you're missing some parts of your `JSON`. I suspect that the start should be `{ "APPL": {"quote": {"symbol":"AAPL", ... } }, "FB": { ... }`, and you left off the initial `{ "APPL": ` portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to write some sort of dynamic struct

No. But you can write a different struct for each type of JSON, and then suck the data into some more universal type. For example, if you have two structs, Ticker1Data and Ticker2Data, then you can have an enum `AnyTicker` whose cases have as associated types the Ticker1Data and the Ticker2Data:

```
enum AnyTicker {
    case ticker1(Ticker1Data)
    case ticker2(Ticker2Data)
}
```

Now a single AnyTicker instance will hold either the Ticker1Data or the Ticker2Data. As soon as you have an enum instance, you can find out what case it is and now the associated data is automatically of the right type.